# How to write a proper If...Else Statement with JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite a beginner in MySQL I just know the totally basic statements, however now I'ts time for me to get into some more difficult, but worth stuff.

I actually have 3 tables in MySQL, here is the representation:

### users:

```
   user_id | name    | country 
   ---------------------------
         1 | Joseph  | US     
         2 | Kennedy | US      
         3 | Dale    | UK
```

### admins:

```
  admin_id | name    | country
  ----------------------------
         1 | David   | UK     
         2 | Ryan    | US     
         3 | Paul    | UK
```

### notes:

```
id | n_id | note                    | comment   | country | type  | manager
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 3    | This is the 1st note    | First     | US      | admin | 2
 2 | 2    | This is the 2nd note    | Second    | US      | user  | 1
 3 | 2    | This is the 3rd note    | Third     | UK      | user  | 2
```

Now I would like to execute something like this SQL (I'm going to type not real commands here, because I'm not really familiar with all of the SQL expressions):

```
  IF notes.type = admin 
    THEN 
        SELECT 
            notes.note, 
            notes.comment, 
            notes.country, 
            admins.name, 
            admins.country 
        FROM notes, admins 
        WHERE notes.n_id = admin.admin_id
    ELSEIF notes.type = 'user'
        SELECT
            notes.note, 
            notes.comment, 
            notes.country, 
            users.name, 
            users.country 
        FROM notes, users 
        WHERE notes.n_id = users.user_id
```

I hope you understand what would I like to achieve here. I could do this easily with more SQL statements, but I would like to try some query which doesn't use that much resources.

---

### Edit 1:

I would like to Get all of the Notes and get which usergroup has submitted it than apply the user's name to it. I mean, if the admin submitted the note, than SQL should choose the ID from the Admin table (as per the type value) but if a User submitted the note, it should get the name from the Users table.

The result should look something similar to this:

```
            result:
            ------
                id | note                    | comment  | country | name
                --------------------------------------------------------
                 1 | This is the 1st note    | First    | US      | Paul
                 2 | This is the 2nd note    | Second   | US      | Kennedy 
                 3 | This is the 3rd note    | Third    | UK      | Kennedy
```

### Edit 2:

I have actually forgot to mention, that all of these should be listed to a manager. So a 'manager ID' should be added to the Notes and list all of the notes where the manager is for example: 2.

Comment: Your best bet, I think, is to do two queries and UNION then together.

Comment: You mean split the table somehow?

Comment: Edited the post for additional explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method that you can do in one query:

```
SELECT n.note, n.comment, n.country, 
       coalesce(a.name, u.name) as name, coalesce(a.country, u.country) as country
FROM notes n left join
     admins a
     on n.n_id = a.admin_id and n.type = 'admin' left join
     users u
     on n.n_id = u.user_id and n.type = 'user';
```

This uses `left join` to bring the records together from both tables.  It then chooses the matching record for the `select`.

To select a particular manager, remove the semicolon and add:

```
where n.manager = 2;
```

Comment: At first this came to my mind, too. Then I thought it would be a little harder to understand because of the two joins and additional coalesce function.

Comment: Added a manager column as well. I'm sorry I've forgot to mention this earlier, I just had a lot on my mind, but it is edited in the first post.

Comment: @trieber . . . I like your query for the original question.  However, the addition of more logic shows that this approach can be simpler (the logic only appears in one place).

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I want to order by with your answer how is it possible?

Comment: @Radical_Activity . . . You would add an `order by` clause with whatever columns you wanted to order by.  The same is true of trieber's solution as well.

Comment: Thanks so much. 've tried your answer and its much more logical and easier to implement!

Answer (score 3):

If you expect admins and users in one result you have got several options. The simplest way is to make a union select like this:

```
SELECT 
    notes.note, 
    notes.comment, 
    notes.country, 
    admins.name, 
    admins.country 
FROM
    notes join admins on notes.n_id = admin.admin_id
WHERE
    notes.manager = 2

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    notes.note, 
    notes.comment, 
    notes.country, 
    users.name, 
    users.country 
FROM
    notes join users on notes.n_id = users.user_id
WHERE
    notes.manager = 2
```

Comment: I don't think so, after OPs last edit I'm pretty sure that's what he expects. Perhaps it would be suitable to add a type column to distinguish between admins and users later.

Comment: I have forgot to mention, that all of these actually connects to a manager ID. So The manager will need to get all of the notes lised with the admin / user name next to the reslts. I guess it would be an additional field WHERE for example the manager ID = 1 (its like we create another column in the Notes table and call it manager). I'm going to update my post.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However as I see now you didn't include the Type column, which is resulted in a way, that the query return a lot of rows even if it was not submitted by the admin. Can you please fit the query to that type, which I've written in the original post?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood correctly. You want to only include rows with type = admin? Just add "AND type = 'admin'" at the end of each where clause. Guess that's what worked now.